# Magento 2 Class does not exist error

Tags: magento2, customer, grid, class

I am trying to create a custom grid in admin, based on customer collection using ui-component.

The problem that I am facing is that I am getting `Class does not exist` error and magento does not tell which class does not exist :|, and I cannot find anywhere in the code the error in this format.

The code from ui-component

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">paid_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Customer</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="paid_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">paid_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">paid_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export Current Page</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export All</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">reports_paid/export/gridToCsv</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected customers?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="subscribe">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">subscribe</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscribe to Newsletter</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massSubscribe"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="unsubscribe">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">unsubscribe</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massUnsubscribe"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to unsubscribe selected customers from newsletter?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">assign_to_group</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options</argument>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">customer/index/massAssignGroup</item>
                        <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">group</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to assign selected customers to new group?</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <!--<columns name="paid_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">-->
    <columns name="paid_columns" class="My_Module\CustomerReports\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.paid_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">paid_listing.paid_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="firstname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Firstname</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="lastname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lastname</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="group_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Group</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_telephone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Since</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="last_visit_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Logged In</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_in">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Created in</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">140</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="kpi_views_customer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Kpi Views</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_membership">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Membership</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_access">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Access</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">222</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Has anyone encountered this type of error ?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the code from your ui-component file?

Comment: Added the code from ui-component

Comment: Does the class `My_Module\CustomerReports\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns` exist ?

Comment: Yes, the class exists

Comment: Hey, please let me know how you resolved this error.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case the XXX\Grid\Collection class does not exist. The file does not exist, but is mentioned in di.xml. My guess is this class should be dynamically created?

Comment: @Wouter can you try my answer? If it doesn't work can you show me your code?

Comment: Hi i am trying to create a Grid and Add New,Edit and form. Getting Warning error

" Warning: class_implements(): Class Vender\Module\Ui\DataProvider\FormDataProvider does not exist and could not be loaded in /vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 71"

Answer (score 3):

To create a custom grid in the admin panel is necessary add this code in **/etc/di.xml** to specify the collection.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">your_main_table</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourResourceModel</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <!--data provider name which used in grid ui component file -->
                <item name="paid_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourModel\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

You can see how your provider data specified **paid_listing.paid_listing_data_source** is specified in the second type with your grid collection.

Comment: @Rahul Mateos, I tried above code but still i am getting same error. can you help me please

Comment: Hi @ErSarveshVTiwari, sorry for the delay, I has been very busy. Can you specify more the error and your code, please?

Comment: I have the same issue,  no more error info :(

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: My di.xml 
https://gist.github.com/giordhano/52451211ed971a5657cc81e2e7aad48e

Listing ui component.xml 

https://gist.github.com/giordhano/5ca8f961f9b625338155f6005c846f3a

Comment: I think that the path of your module in both files is wrong. In the lines 13,22 and 28 in di.xml, you must change your namespace and vendor with the first letter in uppercase. You must change vexsoluciones\facturacionelectronica\.... by Vexsoluciones\Facturacionelectronica\ or Vexsoluciones\FacturacionElectronica\ depending the name of your module. if with theses changes your module doesn't works, tell me it.